# Cannot find linux with old interface

Tags: linux

I am looking for Linux distribution that use simmilar or the same user interface like UBUNTU 9.10
Can you help?

Comment: Maybe try [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/what-is-ubuntu-mate/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like Gnome2. There are two different environments — Cinnamon and MATE. The (meta)package for Cinnamon would be `cinnamon-desktop-environment` and the (meta)package for MATE would be `mate-desktop-environment`. So, for example, to install the complete Cinnamon desktop, you would do `sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment` (or search for and install that package through Synaptic).

Once you install either one (or both!), you should be able to select which one to open when you log in. There's no harm in installing both, since you can select whichever one you want (and set that one as default if you want) when you log in.